# How to do jasmine test case for display none css property using documet.getElementById and getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, css, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to the jasmine test case I tried to do jasmine test case for selection module after doing this style property is getting undefined

```
 function Selection() {

    }
    Selection.prototype.expandFlightDetails = function() {

        document.getElementsByClassName("flight-details-container").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("expandedFlightDetails").style.display = 'block';
    };
    Selection.prototype.hideFlightDetails = function() {
        document.getElementById("expandedFlightDetails").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByClassName("flight-details-container").style.display = 'block';

    };
```

My testcase is

```
describe("selection module", function() {
    var selection;

    beforeEach(function () {
        selection= new Selection();

    });
    afterEach(function () {

    });
    it('expand the flight details part ' , function(){
        selection.expandFlightDetails();
        expect(document.body.getElementsByClassName('flight-details-container')[0].style.display).toEqual('none');

    });
    xit('hide the flight details part ', function(){
        selection.hideFlightDetails();
        expect(document.getElementById('expandedFlightDetails').style.display).toEqual('none');

    });
});
```

After doing this I'm geting and removed code to beforEach

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

please correct me if I have done wrong

Comment: `style` property you used so many time ? at where this error actually came?

Comment: @VikrantKashyap it('expand the flight details part ' , function(){
        flightselection.expandFlightDetails();
        expect(document.body.getElementsByClassName('flight-details-container')[0].style.display).toEqual('none');

    }); for this test case I am getting this error

Comment: Are you including the html file which is having element with class "flight-details-container". ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few errors on this code.

First in `Selection.prototype.expandFlightDetails` make sure to get the first result of the array (you forgot the `[0]`):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("flight-details-container")[0]
```

Same comment for `Selection.prototype.hideFlightDetails`

Then in your test suite you create a Selection instance named `selection` but then in both tests you are using a variable called `flightselection` which is declared nowhere. Shouldn't it be `selection` instead?

Finally your problem seems to be that you try to manipulate `'flight-details-container'` in your test, although this element is created on the `afterEach` callback. `afterEach` means that this will be executed after each test, so it doesn't exist during the test.

Comment: I have edited the code still I am getting the same error.Also I have removed the code from aftereach to beforeach so that each test case the code will executd Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You haven't fixed expandFlightDetails and hideFlightDetails. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array so you need to pick the first item `[0]`

Comment: shouldn't he check if `getElementsByClassName` return at least one element and then pick the first one  ?

Comment: @Pietro this shouldn't be an automatism. Defensive programming can hide bugs sometimes, and if there is no reason for the element to not exist at this moment, then it is better to fail fast. But indeed in a production setup the best may be to avoid crash and send some error feedback to the user instead.